# When Validation Exception is thrown?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to understand when Validation Exception is thrown. As when my custom request  rules method validation fails `$e instanceof ValidationException` returns false, where `$e instanceof HttpResponseException` returns true, and when I `return $e->getResponse` on HttpResponseException it does return the fields that are required so it fires specifically when my custom request validation fails. I have noticed that in Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler class render method has the statement `elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException && $e->getResponse())` but it do not get executed as HttpResponseException is the first one that fires on Rules method validation failure. So I am kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

ValidationException is thrown in the trait `ValidatesRequests`

> see Illuminate / Foundation / Validation / ValidatesRequests.php